# When is filevault2 encrypting my data?

Tags: macos, encryption, authentication

I have turned filevault2 on for my macbook pro. When I log in after booting (after the computer has been completely shut down) the screen is grey, this comes with filevault. On the other hand, when I log in after some time of inactivity or after just closing my computer the screen looks like it always have done.

Are my data encrypted only when the computer is shut down or are my data encrypted also when I get the regular login-screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Apple Support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4790) does a good job of explaining how FileVault 2 works, and what you can do with it. There are two main things that FileVault does for you, and that may be the source of your confusion.

1. It locks your drive. To unlock it, you have to enter your password on the grey screen you see when your computer starts up. From the article:

   > When you select "Turn On FileVault", you're asked to identify the user
   >   accounts that are allowed to unlock the encrypted drive if there is
   >   more than one account present. You'll need to enter the password (or
   >   have users enter their passwords) for each account you want to have
   >   the ability to unlock FileVault 2.
   >
   > Users not enabled for FileVault
   >   unlock are only able to log into the computer after an unlock-enabled
   >   user has started or unlocked the drive. Once unlocked, the drive
   >   remains unlocked and available to all users, until the computer is
   >   restarted.
2. It encrypts your disk. This happens whenever you are logged in to your computer. From the article:

   > The user account that unlocked the drive is automatically logged in
   >   after start up completes. The first time you log in after turning on
   >   FileVault, the initial encryption of your entire hard disk begins. It
   >   should complete within a few hours. This happens in the background,
   >   and doesn't interrupt normal usage of your computer. In addition to
   >   using your computer while encryption is happening, you can sleep, log
   >   out and even turn off your computer during this time. Encryption
   >   continues when your computer is powered on again.

Some clarifications based on the comments below:

The encryption state of the disk has nothing to do with the type of login screen you see.

Once FileVault has gone through the initial phase of encrypting your disk, any new data you add in the future is relatively immediately encrypted. I guess it is theoretically possible that you turn your computer off, or put it to sleep before the new data is fully encrypted, and in that case the encryption of this remaining piece of data will resume once your computer wakes up from sleep, or is turned on.

Note that once encrypted, the data on your disk remains encrypted. It is not affected by whether your computer is turned off or asleep.

The only things that's different is that when your computer is turned off, that automatically locks the disk, and you have to put in a password on the grey filevault screen to unlock it the next time you start up. When you put the computer to sleep, the disk remains unlocked, so you don't see the grey screen when you wake it up. In both cases, the encryption status of your disk remains the same.

Comment: Yes I have read that article but I did not really understand, that's why I asked the question. My interpretation of your answer is the following: The data is not encrypted when I just close the lid (so that I get the regular login-screen after opening the lid again). Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: Yes. By default a MacBook is configured to go to sleep when the lid is closed, and filevault pauses disk encryption when the laptop goes to sleep.

Comment: Just so that we understand each other. I am not talking about the very first encryption of the disk that takes a couple of hours that you refer to as n.o. 2 above but the day-to-day use here. Anyways, I think that you are saying that the data is not encrypted when the lid is closed, and I will shut down my computer every time I want my data to be encrypted.

Comment: Ah, the login screen you see has no impact on the encryption state of the disk. Whether the computer is shut down, or asleep, the encryption state of the disk remains the same. The only thing that changes is the lock state of the disk. I've edit the answer for a longer explanation.

Comment: That did clarify. I am in other words safe by just closing the lid on my computer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually your login screen is visually different when FileVault2 is enabled. It's subtle but different. The password field will have a small question mark button inside to click if you forgot your password, allowing you to enter the Master Key instead. Keep in mind that if you loose the master key, and did not send it to Apple, you will lose all your data.

Comment: I do not see a question mark on my login screen (my non-grey login screen). That's strange..